# "Module not found" error when execute webpack from the CLI command, registered in "/bin" of own library

Tags: node.js, webpack

When I run the webpack, I got error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './StaticallyImportedModules/JsModuleForStaticImport' in 
'D:\OneDrive\PhpStorm\TestProject\FrontendDevelopment\1_Source\0_Devel
opment\3_FrontendScripts'
```

As you see, file is actually exists, and it has been found before I added new features to my project building application based on Webpack:

[image]

What changed is now project building performs by CLI command registered in the `bin/my-lib` (normally frequently added `.js` to files in `bin`, but following [this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-build-a-cli-with-node-js) I did not add the filename extension):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

require('../index').interpretConsoleCommandAndExecute(process.argv);
```

So `interpretConsoleCommandAndExecute` dynamically creates webpack config and run it. Of course, I executed `npm link` to make available my CLI command.

Before ask this question, I collected come information that the cause could be related with `bin/my-lib`, but I did not understand what I have to do.

According console output, webpack finds modules in right directories. What is really wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I just forgot

```
//...
resolve: {
  extensions: [
    '.ts', '.js'
  ]
}
//...
```

in Webpack config.